# Extract segment of filename

Tags: r, stringr

I'm trying to extract a filename and save the dataframe with that same name.
The problem I have is that if the filename for some reason is inside a folder with a similar word, stringr will return that word as well.

```
filename <- "~folder/testdata/2016/testdata 2016.csv"
```

If I run this:

`library(stringr)
str <- str_trim(stringr::str_extract(filename,"[t](.*)"), "left")` it returns `testdata/2016/testdata 2016.csv` when all I want is `testdata 2016`. Optimally it would even be better to get `testdata2016`.

I've been trying several combinations but there has to be a simpler way of doing this. If there was a way of reading the path from right to left, starting at `.csv` stop at `/`, I wouldn't have this issue.

Comment: Look at `?basename`

Comment: You can do this in base R with `gsub(".csv", "", grep(".csv", unlist(strsplit(filename, "/")), value = TRUE))`. Or skip the `strsplit` and `grep` part with `basename`, as @Benjamin suggested.

Comment: This link has an example for removing all of the whitespace under 'Eliminating Whitespace' http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/5748/regular-expressions-regex#t=201704301051180929841

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have below approaches:

```
library(stringr)
str_replace(str_extract(filename,"\\w*\\s+\\w*(?=\\.)"),"\\s+","")

str_replace_all(basename(filename),"\\s+|\\.csv","")
```

You can use `basename` approach as suggested by Benjamin.

```
?basename:
```

> basename removes all of the path up to and including the last path
>   separator (if any).

**Output:**

```
[1] "testdata2016"
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Plenty of help in base R (`tools` pkg comes with the default R install):

```
gsub(" ", "",
  tools::file_path_sans_ext(
    basename("~folder/testdata/2016/testdata 2016.csv")))
```

Comment: No idea this existed. Actually that's exactly what I was searching for. Thank you a lot.